# std::filesystem::file_size() and C++ exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, filesystems

First, I'm assuming it is normal to get C++ exceptions when calling `std::filesystem::file_size()` for a path that doesn't exist. But I'm wondering **why** this happens, and/or what I'm supposed to do to avoid the exceptions?

Generally, I'm under the impression that an exception means I'm taking a wrong turn as the programmer. Is that the case here? From my experience, it seems like most of the file utilities (in Visual Studio at least) throw exceptions over these (seemingly trivial) things, even though you'd expect these conditions to be part of their normal operation and behavior.

Often, I'm calling these functions because I'm unsure about the file and weather it exists. But should I be calling another function to make sure it exists before I request its size, such as `std::filesystem::exists()`? Or is there some way to disable these "minor" exceptions? I know I can disable the exceptions in my compiler so that I do not detect them, but they are still being generated in this case. Any advice on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: There are *two* overloads of [`file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size). One throws exceptions, one doesn't. And while exceptions in C++ have been rare and looked down upon, these days it's getting more common to handle. If you want to use a function that can throw an exception, just make sure to `catch` it?

Comment: You can't selectively disable some exceptions. What you deem to be "trivial or minor" exceptions may be critical for other programs.

Comment: On another note, calling `exists` followed by `file_size` is not atomic. The file could disappear between the calls. Handle errors when the functions you use are documented to return (or throw) errors.

Comment: "First, I'm assuming it is normal to get C++ exceptions when calling std::filesystem::file_size() for a path that doesn't exist. But I'm wondering why this happens, and/or what I'm supposed to do to avoid the exceptions?" - If you call a function that *can* throw an exception, then of course that is "normal". What to do about a path that doesn't exist is entirely up to your program - is it a problem you need to deal with? is it irrelevant? None but you can tell you. What to do to avoid exceptions is impossible to answer. One answer would be "don't call functions that can throw" - not useful.

Comment: If you don't want an exception to propagate from a function that can throw, you can wrap the function in a `try`/`catch`.  If you want to "bottle up" that function & possible exception, you can make a proxy function that does the `try`/`catch` and does whatever handling you deem suitable for your program (ignore? log? re-throw? throw a different exception? return an error code?).

Comment: exception in common are NO sign, that you did something wrong in the code. Exceptions are a (nice) way to handle expected or even unexpected error situation (such as a user giving a non existent path).

Comment: You don't need to get rid of any exception. either pick functions, that do not throw them, or wrap with try {} catch(){} and implement a correct error handling. This means to either rethrow the exception (probably causing the program to abort) or to correct the data within the code if possible and retry or usual way) issue a visible error message and continue in a coordinated way (either request another path or run into a controlled end or just ignore the error if you CAN continue without the results from within the try clause.

Comment: tip: by doing a catch (...) you can catch anything that was thrown, but alas, you won't have a hint about what was thrown (in C, you can thow everything, not only exceptions!)

Comment: @Eljay Nice list of options. I would add "call code to handle the error" & "terminate the program" as other alternative options.

Comment: Disabling exceptions is not a solution. That would be like causing functions to not return error codes. Exceptions are just signals of errors ocuring in your program. Catch them and deal with them just like you would check function calls for error return codes.

Comment: " I'm under the impression that an exception means I'm taking a wrong turn as the programmer. Is that the case here?" generally, no. C++ does not have exceptions all over the place like other languages do. When there are exceptions then they are for things that can happen during runtime, not to signal you made a mistake in code

Comment: I've actually tried to handle the file system exceptions, but have not been able to do so. I'm not sure if this is a VS specific situation, or if I'm just doing something wrong, but my exceptions never seem to be caught. Here is an example of how I have my code written: `try { return std::filesystem::file_size( path ); } catch(const std::filesystem::filesystem_error &ex) { tool::Exception( ex ); return 0; }`

Comment: Also, perhaps I worded the wrong turn statement badly. What I should have said is that I would think getting exceptions every time I run my program would be an indication that I'm doing something the wrong way. Something along those lines. I understand what exceptions are, but I was under the impression that they shouldn't be thrown on a regular basis, unless something crooked is afoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the nonthrowing version of `std::filesystem::file_size`:

```
std::error_code theErrorCode;
auto theSize = std::filesystem::file_size(thePath, theErrorCode); // this won't throw
if (theErrorCode)
{
   // handle error
}
else
{
   // handle success, theSize contains the file size
}
```

or wrap it into your own function, like for example:

```
std::uintmax_t myfilesize(const std::filesystem::path& path, std::error_code& error)
{
  try
  {
    error.assign(0, std::generic_category());
    return std::filesystem::file_size(path);
  }
  catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error& e)
  {
    error = e.code();  
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the no-exception versions of these functions. That makes all of the difference. And it answers my question perfectly.

Comment: I can't wait to see `std::expected` used for things like these